# Toolbar was hidden behind the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigationbar, google-keep

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am trying to configure the following components

Toolbar (Appcompat v7 version)

Navigation Drawer

but my toolbar should be behind navigationbar like google keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `Drawer` below main `View` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

           <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />



    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Lower down in the file means higher up in the Z-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest solution

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!--content_main is my layout you can design your own-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```